# MySQL - maximum packets not allowed

Tags: mysql

My client application will throw an exception with the description above when I am sending a file around 2 megs- I have only little knowledge about mysql back end. Does it mean that I need to set something like "maximum packets" on the mysql server?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Set `max_allowed_packet` in your `my.cnf` MySQL configuration file

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I hit this issue adding a large plugin to Atlassian Confluence. The docs you linked to fixed it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to raise `max_allowed_packet` under `[mysqld]` section in the configuration file (my.cnf).

Answer (score 0):

If your under windows you will need to edit the `max_allowed_packet` in your my.ini file. You can see the [MySQL Ref Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html) for help on this as well.